# Сравнение на схожесть текста и записи из базы данных

Tags: doc, php, mysql

Возникла задача в реализации системы сравнения текстов на схожесть, иными словами на предмет плагиата. Реализация системы на PHP, хранение данных в базе данных MySQL.

Принцип работы заключается в следующем, пользователь открывает страницу и в диалоге загрузки файла на сервер выбирает *.doc файл и загружает его на сервер. Система проводит операции над содержимым doc-файла (очистка от лишних символов, стоп-слов и прочее) записывает результат в базу и проверяет с уже существующими записями в базе на предмет их схожести. Результат сравнения выводится на той же странице.

Может быть, так, что текст внутри doc файла может быть заимствован из нескольких источников, и записи о них могут храниться в базе. В записях также указывается и автор текста. Нужно чтобы результат имел вид - "Загруженный файл имеет схожесть с (перечисление записей в базе, которые имеют схожесть) авторами которых являются (перечисление авторов текстов в записях)".

Возможно ли такое реализовать? Как реализовать такую идею? С чего начать? Хотелось бы выслушать ваше мнение, советы, или ссылки на что то полезное в этом направлении, реализации отдельных моментов, все, что может быть полезным.

Comment: Это не просто сравнение строк, а лингвистический анализ текста проводить надо. Вот и задумайтесь, потяните ли вы, чтоб сравнить, к примеру, такие строки:

    "Во поле березка стояла" === "В поле берёза стояла" // true or false?

Comment: @Deonis легко :)

http://ideone.com/RD30xo

Comment: анализ кстати долгая штука, даже на современных компах. php тут не хорош.

Comment: Вот вот... Кстати, честно скажу, что со [Sphinx][1]-ом знаком поверхностно, но возможно, что для поставленной задачи ТС, он может чем-то помочь: как бы релевантный полнотекстовый поиск... Но это только предположение.

   [1]:http://sphinxsearch.com/

Comment: Вот поэтому задался вопросом тут и на нескольких форумах, чтоб узнать мнение людей в этом более компетентных

Comment: @KIBIs, извиняюсь за шевеление археологической ценности, но как успехи в решении вопроса?) мне он тоже интересен.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно провести анализ на сходство текстов с применением питона, библиотеки numpy, используя косинусное расстояние. Т.е фактически у нас сравниваются отдельные строки по смыслу текста. Что дает очень хорошие результаты. Если Вам еще интересна данная тема- ответьте пожалуйста, распишу решение более подробно.

Comment: Распишите, будь-те уж добры